# Solving integral without fundamental theorem of calculus

Tags: integration

Solve $\int_0^1 3xdx$ without using the fundamental theorem of calculus.

I know that, to solve an integral without the fundamental theorem of calculus, I can find the upper sum and the lower sum. I can write down these sums. However, since they have several variables, how do I obtain just one integral value from them?

Comment: What do you mean several variables?

Comment: For example upper sum $U_p(3x)= \sum_{i=1}^k \frac{3i}{k}$ has i and k

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following your comment, the upper sum of a partition where every subinterval is of equal witdh is $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^k \frac{3i}{k^2} = \frac{3}{k^2}\sum_{i=1}^k i = \frac{3}{k^2} \frac{k (k+1)}{2} = \frac{3}{2}\frac{k+1}{k}$, where $k$ is the number of subintervals. As $k$ goes to $+\infty$, $\displaystyle \frac{k+1}{k} \to 1$ and thus $\displaystyle \frac{3}{2}\frac{k+1}{k} \to \frac{3}{2}$. Therefore the infimum of the upper sums is $\displaystyle \frac{3}{2}$.

Comment: This is the solution I am looking for, but where did the $\frac{k(k+1)}{2}$ part come from?

Comment: @kiwifruit See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF

Comment: @kiwifruit There was actually a mistake, each rectangle has base $\frac{1}{k}$ and height $\frac{3i}{k}$. Therefore the area of each rectangle is $\frac{3i}{k^2}$. And of course you actually need $k$ to go to $+\infty$. I have corrected my answer.

Answer (score 5):

$\int_0^1 3 x dx$ is the area of the triangle of base $1$ and height $3$. So the answer is $3/2$

This result uses just the property if integrals as the area under the curve.

Comment: So it's ok to use the full area without partitioning?

Comment: yes as long as you use the fact that the area of a triangle is half base times height. Looks like this is what is expected.

Comment: It is perfectly acceptable to use formulas from classical geometry to evaluate definite integrals where possible (you will find it needful for a while when confronted with integrals such as $ \ \int_{-1}^1 \ \sqrt{1-x^2} \ \ dx \ , $ which you won't be able to solve directly even using a $ \ u-$ substitution).  Calculus was invented in part to compute the areas of closed curves and surface areas and volumes of solids for shapes which are beyond the "reach" of classical geometry.